# AngularJS image uploader with preview, and sorting features

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

Are there any open source angularjs image unloader plug-ins that supports preview and sorting? If not, what approach would be the easiest to implement one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this lib, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-sortable/0.15.0/sortable.min.js with standard file upload, with some effort, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used php gd library for this purpose before. In my case, I used php to do image thumbnail and sorting. The job angular need to do is call APIs for upload image, list image with datetime/name/size sort etc.

Hope this helps you a bit.